# Unable to connect to memcachedb using libmemcached

Tags: c++, libmemcached, memcachedb

I'm writing a small C++ application that is able to connect to a `memcachedb` instance using the `libmemcached` C++ API.

The `memcachedb` instance was created using the following command:

```
memcachedb -m 64 -p 21201 -A 4096 -u memcachedb -l 127.0.0.1 -H /var/lib/memcachedb -f /var/lib/memcachedb/default.db -U off
```

I am able to retrieve the server STATS by doing:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 21201
stats
STAT pid 1972
STAT uptime 124936
STAT time 1428898165
STAT version 1.2.0
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 5.687019
STAT rusage_system 13.329336
STAT ibuffer_size 512
STAT curr_connections 5
STAT total_connections 12
STAT connection_structures 6
STAT cmd_get 4
STAT cmd_set 4
STAT get_hits 4
STAT get_misses 0
STAT bytes_read 236
STAT bytes_written 2171
STAT threads 4
END
```

To retrieve the server STATS programatically I am using the following code:

```
#include <libmemcached/memcached.hpp>

#include <string>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace memcache;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    std::string host(argv[1]);
    int port;
    istringstream(std::string(argv[2])) >> port;

    printf("%s\n", "Instantiating client");

    Memcache first_client;

    printf("Adding server host=[%s] port=[%d]\n", host.c_str(), port);
    first_client.addServer(host, port);

    printf("%s\n", "Getting server STATS");
    map<string, map<string, string> > my_stats;
    bool gotStats = first_client.getStats(my_stats);

    if (gotStats) {
        printf("%s\n", "Got STATS");
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", "Unable to get STATS");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am compiling the application using the following `Makefile`:

```
CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0
OBJS =      MemcachedExample.o
LIBS =      -lmemcached
TARGET =    MemcachedExample

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
$(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

all:    $(TARGET)

clean:
rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

When I execute the application using the following command:

```
MemcachedExample 127.0.0.1 21201
```

It fails to retrieve the server STATS:

```
Instantiating client
Adding server host=[127.0.0.1] port=[21201]
Getting server STATS
Unable to get STATS
```

What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: can you make a tcpdump over your lo interface and check the trace on wireshark to check possible differences?.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the tcpdump as pointed by @Rastmaj I found that in the dump for the connection via my program there were no packets related with the connection I was trying to establish.

This made me take look at the code of the C++ interface for the C Client Library for memcached. I found that the empty constructor was initializing the `memcached_st` object using `memcached("", 0)` while the constructor receiving `hostname` and `port` arguments not only initialized the `memcached_st` object using `memcached("", 0)` but also added a server using the `memcached_server_add` function.

Though there is no apparent reason why does it work when adding a server just after initializing the `memcached_st` object, since the C++ method `memcache::Memcache::addServer` does exactly the same, the solution I found was simply changing:

```
Memcache first_client;
```

for

```
Memcache first_client("--SERVER=" + host + ":" + std::string(argv[2]));
```

This solves my problem but I still lack an explanation of this behavior, further insights are appreciated.